# Web scraper using BeautifulSoup not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have coded a web scraper for Stack Overflow, but it doesn't work. Apparently, in my soup there are NoneType objects that just came from nowhere. Here's the web scraper code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page='

r = requests.post(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml').find('div', id='questions').find_all('div')

for summary in soup: # FIXME: Prints each question twice
    try:
        print(f'Question: {summary.h3.text}')
        print(f'Tags: {", ".join(summary.find("div", class_="tags").text[1:].split(" "))}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # Prints "'NoneType' has no attribute 'text'" which shouldn't be in the soup
```

The error I get (If you didn't read the comment) is "'NoneType' has no attribute 'text'" which confuses me a lot because of the fact that there are NoneType objects in the soup.

I am using:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8

Comment: Did you try using `.find_all(class_='question-summary')` instead of `.find_all('div')` ? When you use `.find_all('div')`, it targets all the divs from every container. Some of the divs contain nothing that you look for which is what causes that error. Try locating something unique, as in `class`, `id` e.t.c. Btw, you can also use `.find_all('div',recursive=False)` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't `None` type objects in `soup`, rather the calls to

```py
... summary.h3 ...
... summary.find("div", class_="tags") ...
```

Within your loop will return `None` in the case that `summary` does not have a `h3` element, or if there are no `div` elements with a class attribute of `tags` in the current `summary` respectively.

An `Exception` is naturally thrown in these cases as you attempt to access the `text` attribute of a `None` type element.

It could be helpful to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) to show the indices of `soup` which are causing this `Exception` to be thrown.

e.g.

```py
for i, summary in enumerate(soup):
    try:
        print(f'Question: {summary.h3.text}')
        print(f'Tags: {", ".join(summary.find("div", class_="tags").text[1:].split(" "))}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Exception raised during handling of soup[{i}]')
        print(e)
```

It is probably advisable to use the above to gain a deeper understanding of the response structure so that you might best ignore these elements during parsing.

Of course you could always do something lazy like the below to `pass` over any `AttributeError`s thrown within the loop but still print any other kind of `Exception` thrown - though this is obviously not the most efficient approach.

```py
for summary in soup:
    try:
        print(f'Question: {summary.h3.text}')
        print(f'Tags: {", ".join(summary.find("div", class_="tags").text[1:].split(" "))}')
    except AttributeError as ee:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

JP193 has given you the answer in regard to why you get a `NoneType` returned.

The big problem that I have found with you code is that each of the `<div>` you find using `BeautifulSoup(r.text,xml').find('div', id='questions').find_all('div')` arent needed to get the "question" and the "tags", that is why you get a lot of `AttributeError` messages. To condense the `<div>` that are relevant you need to look closer at the code you get as a result of `soup`. To best condense the outcome of `soup` would be to find all the `<div>` with the `class` being `"question-summary"`. So the code should look more like:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser").find("div", id="questions").find_all("div", {"class": "question-summary"})`

After that point it is up to you how you print the results for the 'question' and 'tags'. I have done it like this:

```
    try:
        question = q.find("div", {"class": "summary"}).find('h3')
        print('Question: ' + question.text)

        tags = soup[0].find("div", {"class": "tags"}).text.split()
        print('Tags: ' + ', '.join(tags))
    except AttributeError:
        print('AttributeError div ' + str(int + 1))
```

Put together my solutions is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page='

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser").find("div", id="questions").find_all("div", {"class": "question-summary"})

for int, q in enumerate(soup):
    try:
        question = q.find("div", {"class": "summary"}).find('h3')
        print('Question: ' + question.text)

        tags = soup[0].find("div", {"class": "tags"}).text.split()
        print('Tags: ' + ', '.join(tags))
    except AttributeError:
        print('AttributeError div ' + str(int + 1))
```

Comment: A problem about your code is that ALL questions scraped from the website have a common tag, which is NOT what I want my scraper to do

Comment: What are you looking for? I've tried to read between the lines of your question and the code you have provided. What tags are you looking for?

Comment: I am not looking for specific tags, I just want to get random questions from the website

Comment: What is this line of code meant to do? ```print(f'Tags: {", ".join(summary.find("div", class_="tags").text[1:].split(" "))}')```

Comment: It's meant to print out the tags